# Ugrade tmux from 1.8 to 1.9 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tmux

I was just adding tmux plugins to my .tmux.conf file to find out that one of the plugins (tmux-copycat I think) requires tmux 1.9.  When I start tmux I get the message `Error: Tmux version unsupported.  Please install tmux version 1.9 or greater!".

So, what is the best way to upgrade tmux 1.8 to 1.9 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: How did you install version 1.8?

Comment: I used apt-get install tmux

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**Update**: due to new tmux version and changes in package repository, this answer is updated to show how to install tmux `2.0` (which is better, no reason to use `1.9` anymore).

Here are the steps to update "blank" ubuntu - version 14.04 only (see below for other ubuntu versions):

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common`
3. `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:pi-rho/dev`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install -y tmux=2.0-1~ppa1~t`
6. now if you do `tmux -V` it should show `tmux 2.0` which is a good version for tmux plugins

I verified the above steps on a new digitalocean droplet.

Basically, it's adding the [pi-rho/dev repository](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev), updating and then installing tmux from there.

If you have another ubuntu version you might want to install a different tmux version from the same repo. So:

- ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) step 5: `sudo apt-get install -y tmux=1.9a-1~ppa1~p` (installs tmux `1.9`, no package for tmux `2.0` yet)
- ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) step 5: `sudo apt-get install -y tmux=1.9a-1~ppa1~s` (installs tmux `1.9`, no package for tmux `2.0` yet)
- ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) step 5: `sudo apt-get install -y tmux=2.0-1~ppa1~u`
- ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) step 5: `sudo apt-get install -y tmux=2.0-1~ppa1~v`

Comment: `E: Version '1.9a-1~ppa1~t' for 'tmux' was not found`

Comment: Apparently the package was removed from the repository. I've updated the answer to show how to install tmux `2.0`

Comment: If you already have tmux installed, you can just run `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or `dist-upgrade` if apt says it will be kept) after adding the ppa and updating the sources. Or, if tmux is not installed, you are not compelled to specify the version. `sudo apt-get install tmux` works and installs the latest (2.0+ for the moment)

Comment: Gabriel's comment is the cleaner way to go. for me the specific upgrade command worked: sudo apt-get upgrade tmux

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to add a PPA, you can just build it from source. It's explained in the [`README`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/) on [tmux's GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/README) page:

> To build tmux from a release tarball, do:
>
> ```
> $ ./configure && make
> $ sudo make install
> ```

You might need to install some extra packages to build it. On Ubuntu I needed to install these packages before it would successfully build:

```
exuberant-ctags
cmake
libevent-dev
libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: The best way to get the required packages is `sudo apt-get build-dep tmux`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do #3 above (especially if you are using a corporate proxy that might break ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu
```

If using a tool like Artifactory to act as a caching package proxy

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y http://my.artifactory.site/ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y http://my.domain/artifactory/ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu
```