# tmux showing ^[[I^[[O when losing focus on ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu-14.04, tmux

I initially though this was a vim problem, but it seems like it is tmux problem.
I have executed and made the window lose focus and then regain it:

```
$ sleep 100
^[[I^[[O

$ echo $TERM
screen
```

Here are the options I tried

```
set mouse-utf8 off
set -g status-utf8 on
setw -g utf8 on
```

#### The consequence I see in vim

I have tested my vim with `vim -u NONE`, so I do not think this pertains to my .vimrc configuration. I also see this problem only on my Ubuntu machine and not my CentOS machine:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Reproducing the issue for me simple. I just have to type something on any text click on another window (or C-TAB) and then come back to vim. I am attaching the screenshot.

I have tested the event with -V9 option and I see that s:TextChanged() is being triggered. Here is the output:

```
E349: No identifier under cursor
E39: No identifier under cursor
Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim
1 line less; before #2  6 seconds ago
--No lines in buffer--

  1:    2 afwefasdf

Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim


  1:    1 asdfjkq;wr
```

Is there a way for me silence it without affecting other plugins?

Here is my vim version:
vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

[image: vim crapping out on s:TextChanged()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after spending a half day on this problem. I have decided to just [upgrade to tmux 1.9a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04) from 1.8 and that fixed the problem. I don't know why, but CentOS was affected by 1.8.