# Ubuntu - change tmux 1.8 to tmux-next 1.9

Tags: tmux

After I tried install few plugins for tmux I found that my tmux version is 1.8.

Following steps from this answer I install tmux 2.1: [Ugrade tmux from 1.8 to 1.9 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)
(I didn't found  tmux=1.9a-1~ppa1~t and instead install tmux-next and substitute link in usr bin with `sudo ln -sf $(which tmux-next) /usr/bin/tmux`

Tmux works nicely, but didn't load my config. I tried tmux source, but now I should `tmux source` every time I use tmux.

And after all I get this errors:

```
unknown option: mode-mouse
unknown option: mode-mouse
unknown option: mouse-select-pane
unknown option: mouse-resize-pane
unknown option: mouse-select-window
unknown option: mode-mouse
unknown option: mode-mouse
```

Is tmux-next the same tmux? And what I should do to load **.tmux.conf** automatically?

Comment: This belongs on the Ubuntu SE.

Answer (score 77):

Just have installed tmux 2.1 on Ubuntu Server and faced the same problem. The solution for me is to delete all those unknown options and add those lines instead:

```
 set -g mouse-utf8 on
 set -g mouse on
```

Now in tmux 2.1 I can choose a pane, a window and resize everything with a mouse as it was in tmux 1.8

**MOUSE SUPPORT section of 'man tmux'**:

"The default key bindings allow the mouse to be used to select and resize panes, to copy text and to change window using the status line.  These take effect if the mouse option is turned on."

---

**UPDATE** (*since there are a lot of questions*):

0 **Install:**

```
brew cask install easysimbl
```

1 **Download .dmg file here**: https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/

2 **Execute**:

```
cd /Volumes/MouseTerm && cp -r MouseTerm.bundle /Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins
```

3 **Add this to your .tmux.conf file**:

```
set -g mouse-utf8 on
set -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane   select-pane -t= \; copy-mode -e \; send-keys -M
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \;                 send-keys -M
```

4 **Reload tmux**

5 **Scroll!!!1**

I hope this will help. Works for me on iTerm 2/OS X El Capitan/tmux-2.1

Comment: Thanks. First that I did is comment all mouse options. But anyway tmux don't take ~/.tmux.conf on startup and I don't know where tmux-next store config. One of solutions is alias `tmux='tmux source ~/.tmux.conf'` but it' is doesn't looks like true unix way.

Comment: As I see tmux-next is actually just a package for tmux 2.1 which I installed from source. Sounds weird cause it is supposed to load ~/.tmux.conf file by default and it does on my server. Just in case (as a wild guess) try to load tmux with a backslash to avoid any aliases to be involved. Like: '\tmux'.

Comment: I store all configs in .dotfiles folder. So I tried to change alias to file, but not works. Don't know where to look... Tmux don't source ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: Thanks this works ... But I still cannot get mouse scrolling without entering the copy mode. Is there a solution?

Comment: @dragonxlwang you could try installing this: https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/ and setting up scrolling mode auto enabling on scroll as in the previous tmux versions.

Comment: Scrolling does not work in putty either. Still no solution?

Comment: @dragonxlwang look at my update

Comment: OK, I'll admit that the scrolling works, but it;s soo slow and jerky as to be unusable, at least in iTerm & tmux.

Comment: tmux-next uses ~/.tmux-next.conf  for config (mentioned at https://code.dogfood.paddev.net/~pi-rho/+recipe/tmux-next-daily)

Comment: For tmux version 2.1 , create ~/Library/Application\ Support/SIMBL/Plugins and copy MouseTerm.bundle there.

Comment: to reload new config in all existing tmux shell: `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: @bits I also have a key-binding for this purpose: `bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."`

Comment: @SmileArT, sorry. But after step three I can't copy text =(

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich In order to copy any text in my tmux I press and hold `alt`/`option` (⌥) key to select it and then copy as usual with ⌘-c. On Ubuntu it should be a `Shift` key, I believe.

Answer (score 31):

Options `mode-mouse`, `mouse-select-pane`, `mouse-resize-pane`, `mouse-select-window` are deprecated. Use `mouse` option instead, it covers all the functionality of those four options:

```
set -g mouse on
```

The official deprecation [dates](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/5391342b08f746239e3d0e2f729410af10a54b78/CHANGES#L67-L79) back to v2.1, but the actual changes were [introduced](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/bf635e7741f7b881f67ec7e4a5caa02f7ff3d786) between v1.9 and v2.0.

Comment: This is all I needed.