# tmux 2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 for using window-style and window-active-style

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, ubuntu-15.10, tmuxinator

i like to use the tmux window-style and window-active-style feature to change the background color depending on the fact if a tmux-window is active.

```

## set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'

## set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour250,bg=black'

```

These options are not recognized with tmux-2.0.

I tried to follow the instructions from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952511/4021204 and was able to install tmux-next. when i aliased tmux to tmux-next, tmux-next wasn't recognizing my .tmux.conf file.

So how can i update to tmux-2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do that even on 15.04. First, [download libtinfo5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libtinfo5) (I'm not sure if you need this step on 15.10, may be it comes with sufficient version of libtinfo already). If you run 64-bit system, download **both amd64 and i386** and install it like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_i386.deb libtinfo5_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then [download tmux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/admin/tmux). Now you can just download the amd64 version and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i tmux_2.1-3build1_amd64.deb
```

That's it.